# Getting TypeError: props.children is not a function when trying to set props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set the children values using props but I am getting an error `TypeError: props.children is not a function.`    What am I missing. I want to use SpeakerRendererComponent inside SpeakersRender.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const SpeakerRendererComponent =(props) =>{
    const speakerCollection = [
        {imageSrc:"img1", personName:"Peter"},
        {imageSrc: "img2", personName: "Alexander"},
        {imageSrc:"img3", personName: "Frado"}
    ];

    return props.children({
        speakerCollection:speakerCollection
    });
}

export default SpeakerRendererComponent;


import React from 'react';
import SpeakerRendererComponent from './SpeakerRendererComponent';

function SpeakersRender() {
    return (
        <SpeakerRendererComponent>
            {({speakers}) =>{
                 return (
                    <div>
                      {speakers.map(({ imageSrc, name }) => {
                        return (
                          <img
                            src={`/images/${imageSrc}.png`}
                            alt={name}
                            key={imageSrc}
                          ></img>
                        );
                      })}
                    </div>
                  );
            }};
        
        </SpeakerRendererComponent>
);
};

export default SpeakersRender;
```

Comment: Can't mutate `props.children` like that. What are you trying to accomplish anyway? Can you provide a larger context?

Comment: I want to use SpeakerRendererComponent inside SpeakersRender.

Comment: I see what you're doing. There is a better solution. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set props like that. props are kind of parameters to your function. Once you get that you can't modify them. You can only save them in state or pass them to children components.

If you need to work with the values inside props you can try to maintain a local state for that

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to accomplish and there is a much simpler way to get there. You want to pass a function as a child and then use that function inside the component being called to display information that the component stores locally.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin>
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

  <div id="root"></div>
  
  
  <script type="text/babel">
  
const SpeakerRendererComponent = ({imgFunc}) => {
    const speakerCollection = [
        {imageSrc:"https://via.placeholder.com/140x100", personName:"Peter"},
        {imageSrc: "https://via.placeholder.com/140x100", personName: "Alexander"},
        {imageSrc:"https://via.placeholder.com/140x100", personName: "Frado"}
    ];

    return imgFunc({speakers: speakerCollection})
}

const SpeakersRender = () => {
  const imgFunc = ({speakers}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {speakers.map(({ imageSrc, personName }) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={personName}>
                            <img
                                src={`${imageSrc}`}
                                alt={personName}
                            ></img>
                                {personName}
                                <hr />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <SpeakerRendererComponent imgFunc={imgFunc} />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SpeakersRender />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note how that mapping function is now separated from the element call and is being passed to `SpeakerRendererComponent` as a prop. Now, you will render `SpeakerRendererComponent` and pass the `imgFunc` to it. Then inside `SpeakerRendererComponent` you will call that function with the right data. This will do exactly what you want.

I would gladly load this into CodeSandbox, but it's currently down. I had to test it in my local environment and it works fine.

Comment: Is this approach Render Prop.

Comment: I am trying to pass data using HOC, Renderer Prop and Context. Here I was trying to use Renderer Prop method

Comment: @maxspan Well technically no, because the `return` statement inside `SpeakerRendererComponent` uses a `div` and in a classic Render Props pattern, the return has to reuse the display method that's passed to it. But I just updated my answer to conform to the Render Props pattern by use the return like this `return imgFunc({speakers: speakerCollection})`. Now it's Render Props.

Comment: I am getting this error. SpeakerRendererComponent(...): Nothing was returned from render.

Comment: @maxspan You edited my answer. That's why it doesn't work. Make sure you have this in your `SpeakerRendererComponent`: `return imgFunc({speakers: speakerCollection})` This is a tested and working code.

Comment: actually I edited the answer to make it work.

Comment: @maxspan As I have already mentioned. It's a working code. I have made it runnable right here inside my answer. So give it a try.